# How to obtain all available Entry values

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have created a pop up that would ask for entry, and the amount of entries would depend on the information given.

```
self.e = Entry(self.top, bd = 5)
self.e.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
row = 2
for d in extra:
   self.e2 = Entry(self.top, bd = 5)
   self.e2.grid(column = 1, row = row)
   row = row + 1

def ok(self):
   new = self.e.get().strip()
```

Function ok would be called by a button and then it would return the values. How do I return a list of values from an unknown amount of entries?

Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would put the entries in a list:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(object):

    def __init__(self, top):
        self.top = top
        self.ok_button = Button(self.top, text='OK', command=self.ok)
        self.make_entries()

    def make_entries(self): 
        self.entries = []
        for d in extra:
            e2 = Entry(self.top, bd = 5)
            e2.grid(column = 1, row = row)
            self.entries.append(e2)
            row += 1

    def ok(self):
        values = [e.get().strip() for e in self.entries]

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this. When do I call function make_entries? And what is allowing Entry to store in self.entries?

Comment: @JamestheGreat -- Sorry, I forgot to add `self.entries.append(e2)`  (D'oh!)

Comment: Is "object" any variable that I can put in? Or is this a built-in variable?

Comment: `object` is the builtin base class that all python objects *should* inherit from one way or another.  I've put in some un-tested code that I think should more-or-less work.

Comment: Ok! Let me test this out. Thank you!

Comment: @JamestheGreat -- Of course, I don't _do_ anything with the values.  To check that it's working you'll need to actually do something with them (e.g. print them)